# Partial sorting of small array in OpenCL private memory

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

The task is to find N largest elements in array. The array is quite small (~40 items). I am using this algorithm:

```
    float max1 = -inf;
    int max1I = -1;
    float max2 = -inf;
    int max2I = -1;
    float max3 = -inf;
    int max3I = -1;
    float max4 = -inf;
    int max4I = -1;
    float max5 = -inf;
    int max5I = -1;
    float performances[MAX_NUMBER_OF_SELECTIONS];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSelections; ++i) {
        float performance = /*some calculations*/;
        performances[i] = performance;
        if (performance > max1) {
            max5 = max4; max5I = max4I;
            max4 = max3; max4I = max3I;
            max3 = max2; max3I = max2I;
            max2 = max1; max2I = max1I;
            max1 = performance; max1I = i;
        } else if (performance > max2) {
            max5 = max4; max5I = max4I;
            max4 = max3; max4I = max3I;
            max3 = max2; max3I = max2I;
            max2 = performance; max2I = i;
        } else if (performance > max3) {
            max5 = max4; max5I = max4I;
            max4 = max3; max4I = max3I;
            max3 = performance; max3I = i;
        } else if (performance > max4) {
            max5 = max4; max5I = max4I;
            max4 = performance; max4I = i;
        } else if (performance > max5) {
            max5 = performance; max5I = i;
        }
    }
```

The approach was good enough but now I need to make it top10 instead of top5. Should I copy-paste this pattern? Or maybe there is something better?

Comment: Are you looking for you code to be simple, fast or small? In most cases I would probably use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) structure for something like this.

Comment: I am looking for the fastest solution on GPU.

Comment: Is this part of a larger algorithm? Do you need to find the top10 values ouf 40 values in each thread? Should each block find the top10 out of 40? Or is this the only thing that this kernel should do?

Comment: This is part of a larger algorithm. I need to find top10 in each work item. Each work item has its own array in private memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on a large array this code is NOT valid.
I am supposing that you have lots of small arrays and each work item works on one of them.

I would do something like:

```
//Init
float maxs[10+1];
for(int i=0; i<10+1; i++){
    maxs[i] = -inf;
}

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    //Is it higher than the element 0?
    if(data[i] > maxs[0]){
        maxs[0] = data[i];
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            if(maxs[j] > maxs[j+1])
                swap(maxs[j], maxs[j+1]);
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have an array of 11 elements ordered from small to high, just take the last 10 elements.

The code can be further optimized, but it is very simple.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make a benchmark to compare our approaches to check what's better.

Comment: I've just checked the performance. It works slighty faster than copy-paste solution. Thank you again.